# Insert large Data seed with Migrations, Code First Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have created migration with dummy data. For dummy data i use Bogus. With "Add-Migration" i created Migration. After that I run "Update-Database" and i got Stack Overflow exception. From my research I concluded that is problem in my large data set (10000 records). Before .NET Core I used Laravel and from large dataset seeding I was using array chunks. Is there possibility to also use array chunk in Entity Framework Core or there is another solution?

Error from **Update-Database**:

> Stack overflow.
> at CRM_WEB_Service.Migrations.Coupon.Up(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationBuilder)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Migration.BuildOperations(System.Action`1<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationBuilder>)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Migration.get_UpOperations()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Migration, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator+<>c__DisplayClass16_2.b__2()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(System.String)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(System.String, System.String, System.String)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(System.String, System.String, System.String)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor+UpdateDatabase+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor+OperationBase.Execute(System.Action)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor+UpdateDatabase..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IOperationResultHandler, System.Collections.IDictionary)
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean, Boolean)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Object[])
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, System.Object[])
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor.Execute(System.String, System.Object, System.Collections.IDictionary)
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.InvokeOperationImpl(System.String, System.Collections.IDictionary)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.InvokeOperation(System.String, System.Collections.IDictionary)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.UpdateDatabase(System.String, System.String, System.String)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DatabaseUpdateCommand.Execute(System.String[])
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(System.String[])
> at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(System.String[])
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(System.String[])

Code from **DataContext**:

```
        Randomizer.Seed = new Random(8675309);

        var ids = 1;
        var PromotionCode = new[] { "V27", "V25", "V13", "V21", "V22" };

        var coupon = new Faker<Coupon>()
            .RuleFor(c => c.Id, f => ids++)
            .RuleFor(c => c.GUID, f => f.Random.Guid())
            .RuleFor(c => c.VoucherPromotionCode, f => f.PickRandom(PromotionCode))
            .RuleFor(c => c.PromoCode, (f, c) => c.VoucherPromotionCode + f.Random.Replace("*-****-****"))
            .RuleFor(c => c.AvailableQuantity, f => f.Random.Number(0, 10))
            .RuleFor(c => c.UsageCount, f => f.Random.Number(0,10))
            .RuleFor(c => c.MaxUsageCount, (f, c) => c.UsageCount + c.AvailableQuantity)
            .RuleFor(c => c.Ammount, f => ReturnCleanNumber(f.Random.Double(100, 400)))
            .RuleFor(c => c.ValidFrom, f => f.Date.Between(Convert.ToDateTime("2020-12-01 00:00:00"), Convert.ToDateTime("2021-01-01 00:00:00")))
            .RuleFor(c => c.ValidTo, f => f.Date.Between(Convert.ToDateTime("2021-01-01 00:00:00"), Convert.ToDateTime("2021-05-30 00:00:00")))
            .RuleFor(c => c.ExpiryDate, (f, c) => c.ValidTo)
            .RuleFor(c => c.MinimumValueCurrency, (f, c) => Convert.ToDouble(ReturnCleanNumber(f.Random.Double(100, 300))) + c.Ammount)
            .RuleFor(c => c.CouponTypeId, f => f.Random.Number(1,2))
            .RuleFor(c => c.CouponStatusId, (f,c) => GetCouponStatus(c.UsageCount, c.ExpiryDate))
            .RuleFor(c => c.CreatedDate, f => f.Date.Between(Convert.ToDateTime("2020-12-01 00:00:00"), Convert.ToDateTime("2021-01-01 00:00:00")));

        for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        {
            var coupons = coupon.Generate(100);

            foreach(var c in coupons)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Coupon>().HasData(c);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: I've ran into this issue off and on with [one of my open-source projects](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/tree/master/services/Directory/FilterLists.Directory.Infrastructure.Migrations/Migrations). With your code above, I think if you were able to actually run the migration, you would generate some massive migration files  which could be unwieldy in source control, etc. I think native EF seeding just isn't great for large datasets. At least, not yet.

Comment: Yes, the migration file was large, etc 14 MB. I understand that EF seeding is not great solution for now, Do you have some other solution through code create large dataset, or I need to create dataset with some other datagenerator?